# Como Puedo Enviar los Datos A un Controlador Post Sin que los Datos Enviados Se Pierdan? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Transactions", "Transactions", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "formulario" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" id="rangofecha" name="rangofecha" class="form-control pull-right" />
                        </div><!-- /.input group -->
                        @Html.DropDownList("ConveniosList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ConveniosList"], new { @class = "form-control pull-right", @id = "ConvenioId", @style = "color:black;" })
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i>Ref.</i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" id="referencia" name="referencia" class="form-control pull-right" />
                        </div><!-- /.input group -->

                        @Html.ValidationMessage("rangofecha", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div><!-- /.form group -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>  Buscar</button>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos Datos que se Muestran en pantalla me gustaria Mantenerlos Cuando El Post Devuelva el

> ActionResult

Comment: Intenta regresando el mismo objeto que recibiste, en el `Controller` ponle `return View(myObject);` obviamente cambia `myObject` por el objeto recibido en el `Action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias opciones para hacer lo que quieres, acá te voy a indicar una usando ViewData:

Tu acción que recibe el POST debe ser algo como lo siguiente:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(datetime fecha, string referencia)
{
    // Acá va tú código

    ViewData["fecha"] = fecha;
    ViewData["referencia"] = referencia;

    return View();
}
```

Ahora debes cambiar el código en tu vista para que puedas usar estos valores, por ejemplo en el input de referencia:

```
<input type="text" id="referencia" name="referencia" class="form-control pull-right" value='@ViewData["referencia"]' />
```

Puede que también necesites inicializar el ViewData en tu acción GET:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Acá va tú código

    ViewData["fecha"] = DateTime.Now;
    ViewData["referencia"] = String.Empty;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano. Me ha servido a la perfeción. Saludos desde Republica Dominicana.

Comment: Que bien!!! Me alegra que te haya funcionado.